# Alfresco: changing date and time formats

Tags: date, datetime, alfresco

I have a few places where I need to change how the date format displays in my Alfresco share:

---

**Calendar Format**

[image: Calendar Format]

Needs to be in MM/DD/YYYY format.

---

**Date in Info.ftl Control**

[image: InfoFTL]

Needs to be in DDD MM DD YYYY format.

---

**Date().toString()**

[image: Date()]

This is being displayed in a data list. Ideally it should read: "Tue Jul 2015 8:27:51 (EST)"

---

I located common.properties and made the following changes:

```
## Date Formats
#Used client side (uses Alfresco.util.formatDate)
date-format.default=mmm ddd d yyyy HH:MM:ss
date-format.defaultDateOnly=mmm ddd d yyyy
date-format.shortDate=m/d/yy
date-format.mediumDate=mmm d, yyyy
date-format.mediumDateNoYear=mmm d
date-format.longDate=mmmm dd, yyyy
date-format.longDateNoYear=mmmm dd
date-format.fullDate=mmmm, d dddd, yyyy
date-format.fullDateTime=mmmm, d dddd, yyyy 'at' h:MM TT
date-format.shortTime=h:MM TT
date-format.mediumTime=h:MM:ss TT
date-format.longTime=h:MM:ss TT Z
date-format.monthYear=mmmm yyyy
date-format.dayDateMonth=mmmm, d dddd
date-format.am=am
date-format.pm=pm
```

But none of them seem to affect any date formats anywhere. My questions:

1. Where do I need to make additional changes to get the above formats to work?
2. How do I change the time zone?

Essentially, I need to change everything to Eastern US time zone and formats.

Comment: Did you make sure that the locale on the server running your Alfresco is set to US?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: My Alfresco is running on Windows.

Comment: Check the regional settings then, and ensure that the server thinks it's on the US east coast and has a US localisation set

Comment: I've searched around and have been unable to find where these settings are located.

Comment: Depends on your version of Windows. For at least some versions, [you can follow this Microsoft information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/change-country-region-setting#1TC=windows-7), otherwise best ask a new question on that one topic on ServerFault or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different files where date format are mentioned. Each of them are responsible for rendering dates in different places

```
<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\form.get_en.properties

 <ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\common.properties

<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages
common.properties\slingshot.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the form.get_en.properties, would it be possible to set HH:MM (24 Hour) to HH:MM (12 Hour) and have it work?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to find the time zone property in slingshot.properties.

Comment: you are right no date related properties in slingshot file. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We need to edit the \tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\common.properties as well as \tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\common_en.properties the second file the locale specific file should also be modified.

Modify the below key's value

date-format.default=**mm/dd/yyyy**

These changes only impact the display format of date, if we need to make changes for form we need to modify in \tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form**form.get_en.properties** and form.get.properties.

Hope this will help you :)